# How to write Parquet files on HDFS using C++?

Tags: c++, hdfs, parquet

I need to write in-memory data records to HDFS file in Parquet format using C++ language. I know there is a parquet-cpp library on github but i can't find example code.

Could anybody share copy or link to example code if you have any? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples for parquet-cpp in the github repo in the [`examples`](https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp/tree/master/examples) directory. They just deal with Parquet though, and do not involve HDFS access.

For HDFS access from C++, you will need [libhdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html) from Apache Hadoop. Or you may use Apache Arrow, which has HDFS integration, as desribed [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/md__h_d_f_s.html).